# How can a process be notified when a non-child process changes state (e.g. stopped)?

Tags: linux, unix

What mechanisms are available to query the status of a task in linux, given the process performing the query is unrelated to the task being queried?

Ideally, the process performing the query is informed when the non-child process changes its state (e.g. into stopped after it receives a `SIGSTOP` signal), such as waking up the querying process when this event occurs.

Currently, to get this information, I can only think of reading the `/proc/{queried PID}/status` periodically to determine whether the process being queried has stopped.

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). The short answer is to use the same facilities used by debuggers. Read `man 2 ptrace`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @KurtisRader. Do you mind editing the question so it is more appropriate? I am looking for a way for a process to sleep and be woken up when a task changes state. That is the gist of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "changes state"? For example, when it blocks on an I/O that is a state change but that isn't something you can be notified about. And why do you need to track a processes "state" (whatever that means)?

Comment: Changing state is when the proc/PID/status state field changes from R (running) to T (stopped). [This reference](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) shows other possible states

Comment: As for why, I would like to know when it goes from running to stopped. After the process is in the stopped state, attaching to one of the threads with ptrace would then allow me to modify the process' address space state in a thread-safe manner, by executing only one of the threads (controlled via ptrace).